Strange speed behavior with a Samsung External SSD T7
I have a Samsung SSD T7. Several days ago I start noticing a strange problem:

INTERFACE2
USB 3.2 Gen 2 (10 Gbps), backwards compatibility

DIMENSION (WxHxD)
85 x 57 x 8.0 mm

WEIGHT3
72 g

TRANSFER SPEED4
Up to 1,050 MB/s

UASP MODE
Supported

ENCRYPTION
AES 256-bit hardware encryption

SECURITY
Samsumg Portable SSD Software 1.0
(*Optional Password Protection)

CERTIFICATION
CE, BSMI, KC, VCCI, C-tick, FCC, IC, UL, TUV, CB, EAC

RoHS COMPLIANCE
RoHS2

When I connect the drive to a USB port, and start copying something (from/to SSD) in the first 4-5 minutes the drive works at a very low speed (10-20 kb/s).
And after that suddenly the speed begin to rise and after works at full speed.
I've tried this drive on several computers, in USB 3.0 or 2.0 ports, and it's the same situation.
I've tried to reformat but without success.
What can I do?

Please, add to your post the motherboard model and specs.

First, check the ssd health with Crystal DiskInfo.

Did you already try the ssd on other computer?

If this new behavior os consistent across multiple computers/devices and connections, the problem is the drive.
Drives are not repairable. Faults on a drive are always indicative of either reduced capability due to aging or impending total failure.
If the drive is new, warranty replace it. If the drive is not under warranty any longer, retire and replace it.

And how do you explain that for 4-5 minutes the problem occur , and after everything is ok ? If the drive is damaged , it should be always and not only for the first 4-5 minutes , and after works ok.

Drives are largely "black boxes" we don't get to see or manipulate inside them, especially modern SSDs, which are controlled by their own controllers, and what you "see" at the system level is abstracted. Drives are quite reliable, until they aren't, and a drive giving you some signal of a problem is good, because it gives you opportunity to backup your data and replace the drive. I gave the appropriate diagnostic tasks in my first paragraph: if the behavior is consistent across multiple systems you connect this drive to, this means the problem is the drive. You can't fix the drive.

I did a low level format , and the problem disappear.

You said in the question you'd formatted. Can you explain the difference between the format you'd done prior to asking and this "low level format" that you've done since?

@music2myear Before i did a normal format.The difference you can read here : https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/ssd-low-level-format-0001.html

It might have been sufficient to run the "TRIM" command on the drive. For example, in Windows, right-click the drive, choose "Properties", select the "Tools" tab, click the "Optimise" button, select the drive, then click the "Optimise" button in that dialog.

In point of view, that doesn't make sense at all. Issue's possibly something else. Did you check the ssd health before realizing that low level formating?
